# Mule ESB - Database Connector bulk mode with dynamic table name

Tags: database, mule, bulk, connector

When I tried to use "Bulk Mode" with dynamic table name (Ex: #[flowVars.sfdcTableName]) in database connector, it fails. It works fine if i hardcode the table name in the parameterized query. Did anyone encounter this issue? Can anyone please tell how can this be resolved to use "bulk mode" with dynamic table name? Thanks much. First one works and second one fails.

```
    <db:insert config-ref="APP_Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
    <![CDATA[INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (Id) Values (#[payload.Id])]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>

    <db:insert config-ref="APP_Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
    <![CDATA[INSERT INTO #[flowVars.sfdcTableName] (Id) Values (#[payload.Id])]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

Comment: There were few issues reported in jira for bulk mode with parameterized queries https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7416  and https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8283 make sure you haven't bumped into those ... which mule version are you using ?

Comment: Thanks, dynamic table name wont work with parameterized-query but only with dynamic query. I had to build a dynamic query using Groovy before calling the database connector with dynamic query. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound crazy.. But try wrapping the MEL in single-quotes. I know. It's silly, but it has resolved similar issues for me in the past.

Otherwise your DB name FlowVar isn't being set correctly or it's invalid for your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  Anirban Sen Chowdhary and StoicNZ, dynamic table name wont work with parameterized-query but only with dynamic query. I had to build a dynamic query using Groovy before calling the database connector with dynamic query. It worked great!!.

SJ